# Handling a JS POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a ruby on rails website that also has javascript.

I have this javascript code, that I made, that makes a POST to the website and completes the action that I want it to.

```
  function create_group_item(group_id, items_id){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/group_items/create/',
      data: { "group_id": group_id, "items_id": items_id },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  }
```

This works and is fine.

The issue I have is calling that same POST function from another rails controller instead of with javascript. I want to create a group_item from inside the item controller.

I have a variable in my item controller: `group_item_info = {"group_id" => group_id.to_i, "item_id" => item_id}`
Which, when I print it reads out: `{"group_id"=>15, "item_id"=>754}` in some instances. So, I have no issue getting the values of the group and item.

**QUESTION**
How do I call the group_items create function from the items controller.

**Attempts so far**
code such as:

```
@group.items << @item
```

and

```
def create_group_item
    redirect_to url_for(:controller => :group_items_controller, :action => :create)
end
```

then: `create_group_item({group_id: group_id, items_id: item_id})`

have only given me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
group_item_info = {"group_id" => group_id.to_i, "items_id" => item_id}
@group_item = GroupItem.new group_item_info
if @stand_item.save
    flash[:notice] =  "#{@item.name} has been added to your group."
else
    flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong adding this item to your group, try again later."
end
```

One main thing which I had wrong in the other code included `items_id` vs `item_id`